# Working with optionals in dartjs

Tags: dart

Newbie in dart js. OK, I understand the concept of optional parameters, very similar to C#, but I am not quite sure why the following gives the result it does:

```dart
void main() {
  print(SayInFunction('Joe', suffix : ' Sir'));
}

String SayInFunction(name, {suffix : " Junior"}) => SayHello(name + suffix);

String SayHello(name, {suffix : " Senior"}) => ('Hello $name $suffix');
```

Here is the return:

```
Hello Joe Sir  Senior
```

Why am I wrong in thinking it should be:

```
Hello Joe Sir
```

PS: If it has to do with the $signs, how should I restructure the SayHello function to return 'Hello Joe Sir' ?

Answer:

```
String SayInFunction(name, {suffix : " Junior"}) => SayHello(name, suffix: suffix);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to call `SayHello(name, suffix: suffix);` to get the desired result.
You effectively call `SayHello('Joe Sir')` and because you don't provide a suffix `SayHello` takes the default `' Senior'`

Comment: And you understand why it has to be this way?

Comment: Yes I do. I erred in adding 2 values in the first parameter when my intention was to provide 2 params. Since I did not provide 2, the default was 'Senior'.

Comment: It's the same with `SayInFunction` where you did it right. When calling `SayHello` you concatenate `name + suffix` and this value is provided to `SayHello` as parameter `name`, but nothing is assigned to parameter `suffix` because you pass only one value and therefor the default value is assigned.